# How to put Hokuyo laser sensor on p2os?

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi! I'm new at gazebo, and I would like to know how to put a hokuyo sensor on my p2os model. I am not using a real robot, I just want to know how to add a sensor on my simulation.

I've tried https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/fb8354a98ac5/turtlebot_description/urdf/gazebo.urdf.xacro (turtlebot_sim_laser) Sensor insertion into robot's urdf: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/fb8354a98ac5/turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_body.urdf.xacro (laser_joint) but it still doesn't work. (Check http://answers.ros.org/question/44691/how-to-put-hokuyo-laser-sensor-on-p2os/)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/30/how-to-put-hokuyo-laser-sensor-on-p2os?/) by [Mendelson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/35/mendelson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

If you're using [SDF](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Sdf_format), then you can nest models using:

```
<model name="pioneer2dx">
  <include filename="pioneer2dx.model" />
  <include filename="hokuyo.model" model_pose="0.2 0 0.3 0 0 0" />
  <include filename="camera.model" model_pose="0.2 0 0.5 0 0 0" />
</model>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0